# Reversing for loop in certain conditions

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Generally I want to process my list from the bottom up:

```
for ($dp = sizeof($products) - 1; $dp >= 0; $dp--) {
```

but *sometimes* I want to do it from the top down:

```
for ($dp = 0; $dp < sizeof($products); $dp++) {
```

Is there a way to express this in a single line of code?

Comment: You can probably make use of `array_reverse`. Something like `foreach(($reversed ? array_reverse($products) : $products) as $product)`

Comment: You can initialise `$dp` before the loop, and do something like `for (; $reverse ? $dp < ... : $dp >= 0; $dp += $reverse ? 1 : -1)`… Though that's not terribly readable. Perhaps rather put the loop body into a function and do two different loops calling that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($dp = 0; $dp < sizeof($array); $dp++) {
    $item = $array[$reversed ? sizeof($array) - $dp - 1 : $dp];
}
```

OR, if the value of `$dp` is what's important in the body of the loop, change the counter and compute it:

```
for ($pos = sizeof($products) - 1; $pos >= 0; $pos--) {
   if (!$reversed) {
       $dp = $pos;
   } else {
       $dp = sizeof($products) - $pos - 1;
   }
```

Comment: Interesting idea but I need $dp in the block of the array as an index. Still, using your approach I could calculate the index and put it in a new variable.

Answer (score 2):

Define yourself a function that yields values in the desired direction:

```
function iterate($iterable, $forward = true) {
    $init = $forward ? 'reset' : 'end';
    $next = $forward ? 'next'  : 'prev';
    for ($init($iterable); ($key=key($iterable))!==null; $next($iterable)){
        yield $key => current($iterable);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
$array = [ 'q', 'l', 'z' ];

// forward...
foreach (iterate($array) as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value" . PHP_EOL;
}

// now backward...       VVVVV
foreach (iterate($array, false) as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This approach insulates you from the errors associated with index juggling.

[See it online at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/cXE09)

Comment: clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
// first determine direction of traversal and
// initialize your $dp index at the appropriate end of $array
$step = $someCondition? 1 : -1;
$dp = $step > 0 ? 0 : sizeof($array)-1;

//use a while loop    
while($dp < sizeof($array) && $dp >=0 && !empty($array) ):
   $item = $array[$dp];
   $dp += $step;
endwhile;
```